# How to use drag option to move row in gridView

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, asp.net, drag-and-drop

I want to use drag option to move row of gridview. But using my code, drag is not is working.
Tried code is:

```
**// using C# code**
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        DataRow row = null;
    System.Data.DataColumn tColumn = null;      // TABLE COLUMNS. 

            tColumn = new System.Data.DataColumn("Database Column", System.Type.GetType("System.String"));
            dt.Columns.Add(tColumn);
            dt.Rows.Add("Title");
            dt.Rows.Add("FirstName");
            dt.Rows.Add("MiddleName");
            dt.Rows.Add("LastName");
    GridView3.DataSource = dt;
            GridView3.DataBind();
    }

**//using .aspx code**
        <asp:GridView ID="GridView2"  CellPadding="5" CellSpacing="0"  OnRowDataBound="GridView2_RowDataBound" 
                        ForeColor="#333"          runat="server">

                        <HeaderStyle BackColor="#989898" ForeColor="white" />

                    </asp:GridView>
        **// .js code**
        <script type="text/javascript">
               $(document).ready(function () {
                   $("#GridView2").tableDnD();
               });
    </script>
```

I am using code, but this code is not working. 
After edit..
My js plugin is:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://github.com/isocra/TableDnD/blob/master/js/jquery.tablednd.0.7.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Comment: "Not working" isn't an error message or problem statement. We can't fix "not working" in code, any more than a mechanic can fix a car that is "not working", without any other information about the problem. How is it not working? What exactly happens when you run the code?

Comment: P.S. We have no idea what the `.tableDnD()` method does. Is it from some plugin? If so please mention the plugin and provide a link to the documentation.

Comment: It would also help a lot more if you show the final HTML rendered by your aspx & C# code. Any jQuery code will operate on the HTML directly, not on the aspx. So if the aspx does not produce what you expect or what is compatible with your drag and drop plugin, that could contribute to the issue. You can see the rendered HTML using your browser's element inspector (in the Developer Tools) or via your browser's View Source screen, after you have loaded the page. Please paste the HTML which is created from the gridview into your question for us to look at, thanks.

Comment: @ADyson Please check my edited question

Comment: Please also add the HTML as I already requested above. Thankyou.

Comment: Also, any reason you use an old version of tableDnD? 0.9.1 is the latest version - see https://github.com/isocra/TableDnD